# I want to take the email from the following value as Reply to address in my message

Tags: php, email

My Javascript

```
var dataString = 'Name='+ name + '&Email=' + email + '&Phone=' + phone + '&Comment=' + comment;
```

---

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail2.php",
      data: dataString,
```

---

PHP mail script (mail2.php):

```
$headers .= 'From: <admin@somedomain.com>' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: ' . $Email . "\r\n"; <-- This is not working
```

Please help.

Comment: you need to write $_POST['email'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing data using post method in ajax. so you will get your data in post in mail2.php file.

**PHP mail script (mail2.php):**

**Wrong**

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $Email . "\r\n"; <-- This is not working
```

**Correct code**

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['Email'] . "\r\n";
```

Comment: That worked perfectly,  Thanks a lot @Ruchish Parikh.. :)